# Why are not long press begin / end detected in Xamarin IOS customrenderer accurately?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uibutton

I have a Xamarin Forms project, in which I'd like to have a button, that must be pressed **long** to trigger an event. Beside long press event I need also the **exact time of touching down** the button, because that time I'd like to start some animation on the UI.

I made a custom renderer to solve it, on Android it works, but on IOS I have problems: sometimes it works, sometimes does not.

On IOS I made it like this: I use TouchDown event to get the exact time of touching, TouchUpInside the end and UILongPressGestureRecognizer the long press. Sometimes it works like a charm, but **sometimes only UILongPressGestureRecognizer's event fired without triggering TouchDown before**.

Here is my code:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(LongPressButton), typeof(LongPressButtonRenderer))]

 namespace AnyProj.iOS
{
public class LongPressButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
{
    private LongPressButton _longPressButton;

    private UILongPressGestureRecognizer _longPressGestureRecognizer;

    public LongPressButtonRenderer()
    {

    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        _longPressGestureRecognizer = new UILongPressGestureRecognizer(() => HandleLongPress());

        if(e.NewElement == null)
        {
            if (_longPressGestureRecognizer != null)
            {
                this.RemoveGestureRecognizer(_longPressGestureRecognizer);
            }
        }

        if(e.OldElement == null)
        {
            _longPressButton = (LongPressButton)e.NewElement;
            Control.TouchDown += (sender, ee) => {
                Debug.WriteLine("Sometimes triggered, sometimes not.");
            };
            Control.TouchUpInside += (sender, ee) => {
                Debug.WriteLine("Sometimes triggered, sometimes not.");
            };
            _longPressGestureRecognizer.MinimumPressDuration = 2.0;
            this.AddGestureRecognizer(_longPressGestureRecognizer);
        }
    }

    private void HandleLongPress()
    {
        try
        {
            if (_longPressGestureRecognizer.State == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began)
                Debug.WriteLine("Sometimes triggered, sometimes not.");
        }
        catch(Exception exc)
        {
            Debug.Assert(false,exc.Message);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Would you be so kind to help me how to improve it? Thanks a lot!

Update:
It happens on real device (IPhone SE), on simulator it always works like a charm!

Update 2: I made a tiny test project in Swift to implement this functionality, and works great, so there is no similar error like via Xamarin forms.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var longPressButton: UIButton!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    longPressButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(touchDown), for: .touchDown)
    longPressButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(touchUp), for: .touchUpInside)

    let longGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longTap(_:)))
    longGesture.minimumPressDuration = 2.0
    longPressButton.addGestureRecognizer(longGesture)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@objc func touchUp(){
    print("Touch up")
}

@objc func touchDown(){
    print("Touch down")
}

@objc func longTap(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer){
    print("Long tap")
    if sender.state == .ended {
        print("UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded")
    }
    else if sender.state == .began {
        print("UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan.")
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Are you using real device to test this? I test your code and it always works fine. Or try to use `Control.AddGestureRecognizer(_longPressGestureRecognizer);`. Moreover if `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` triggers, `TouchUpInside` will not fire. You can capture this by using  `_longPressGestureRecognizer.State == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended`.

Comment: Yes, I test it n real device (IPhone SE). On simulator it always works. I will test your other suggestions, thanks!

Comment: Your suggestions did not solve my problem, thanks a lot anyway

Comment: Since I can't reproduce your issue, I think whether it is the problem of your particular device. You may test it on another device if possible. I run it on my iPhone and everything works like a charm.

Comment: Now it is tested on 2 IPhone SE devices, and this occurs on both.

Answer (score 2):

I have tested the following code in my project, and it is working fine. Tested on an iPhone 5c physical device. Note that `HandleTouchUpInside` will not be called if the long press begins; instead you can determine the end from the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`'s `UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended` state.

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);

    if (e.OldElement != null)
    {
        RemovePressEvents();
    }

    if (e.NewElement != null)
    {
        AddPressEvents();
    }
}

private void AddPressEvents()
{
    _longPressGestureRecognizer = new UILongPressGestureRecognizer(HandleLongPress);
    Control.TouchDown += HandleTouchDown;
    Control.TouchUpInside += HandleTouchUpInside;
    AddGestureRecognizer(_longPressGestureRecognizer);
}

private void RemovePressEvents()
{
    Control.TouchDown -= HandleTouchDown;
    Control.TouchUpInside -= HandleTouchUpInside;
    RemoveGestureRecognizer(_longPressGestureRecognizer);
}

private void HandleTouchDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("TOUCH DOWN");
}

private void HandleTouchUpInside(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Note: will not be called if the Long Press begins. Instead,
    // You can determine the end of the press from when HandleLongPress
    // is called and UILongPressGestureRecognizer.State = 
    // UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("TOUCH UP INSIDE");
}

private void HandleLongPress(UILongPressGestureRecognizer o)
{
    switch (o.State)
    {
        case UIGestureRecognizerState.Began:
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("LONG PRESS BEGAN");
            break;

        case UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended:
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("LONG PRESS ENDED");
            break;
    }
}
```